# estimating parameters of gamma distribution

Tags: statistics

My question is, how to vary the sample sizes from the real life data? 
I mean in the r code, before I was using rgamma(n,shape,scale) for the generated data, but now I have a real life data i.e length of stay at the hospital. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Broad topic, much studied. MLE for shape param can be messy. // Suggest you google `gamma distribution` and read esp. Wikipedia. Also, `gamma parameter estimation` and read esp. stat.stackexchange for Huber's comments on computational stability. // Rice suggests bootstrap CIs. Bain & Englehardt Exmp 9.2.12 has rational approx for MLE of shape parameter from Greenwood & Durand (1980). // After all that, if you have specific difficulties, try asking specific question here (math) or on stat.stackexchange (comp).

Comment: thanks BruceEt, have alreday written my code for estimating the parameter of the gamma distribution, mle for shape parameter was obtained using newton Raphson iterative  method. but the problem am having is aw do i apply this code for length of stay hospital data am having at hand varying the sample sizes and the parameters. have already done that without the real life data using rgamma(n,scale,shape) for different sample sizes and different parameters values but i need to be able to apply this to the real life data also. thanks

Comment: Not sure I see your exact difficulty. Is it to set sample size to achieve a CI of a specific width? If so, then I don't think there is a tidy formula. But if your data on length of hospital stays are really gamma distributed, your experiments with simulated data should provide some useful guidance.